# How to throttle wireless speed on Macbook Airport sharing?

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook, airport

I am trying to simulate poor wifi connection conditions using my Macbook as an access point (using Airport sharing)

Any idea to reduce the wireless speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have Lion, you can use the [Network Link Conditioner](http://mattgemmell.com/2011/07/25/network-link-conditioner-in-lion/) to simulate all kinds of network states.

Comment: Is there anything for Snow Leopard?

Comment: ipwf? http://www.askbjoernhansen.com/2004/09/22/mini_tutorial_f.html